# c# opening up Picture folder

Tags: c#

*Today is my first day at learning C#, or any programming language so sorry if I get some terms wrong*

I have a way of doing this but not the way I'd like and want to know if there's a better solution. Aim is, on my C# program, when you click a button, it opens up the Picture folder.

I use the following code to do so:

```
private void picBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Pictures");
}
```

The code works however where MYUSERNAME is, that is fixed. What if I was to run the program on another machine account where the username is different. Is there a way to auto detect the name?

Comment: try Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

Comment: @Invernomuto thanks i'll just read the manual now and give it a shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `MyPictures` or `CommonPictures` member of the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
```

`MyPictures` will go to the folder you are looking for (current user's pictures). But if you wanted to go to the common/shared pictures folder, `CommonPictures` would work.

Comment: Can't you just pass the path, and the OS should figure out which program to use (for folder - explorer, for files - the current selected default for that file type) ?

Comment: He's looking to specifically launch windows explorer opened to the My Pictures folder. He's not trying to launch the default application for a specific file type; just to simply open up My Pictures

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
```

Special folders enumeration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx